# CSS selector not working on react CSS module

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react component with those things:

CSS:

```
.carousel-container > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.carousel-container.render-1 > * {
  width: calc(100% - 10rem);
}
```

JSX:

```
import './carousel.css'

<div className={classNames('carousel-container', 'render-1')}>
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

Everything works well, the div item is set with the width from c**arousel-container.render-1**

But when I tried to do the same using React CSS Module the div item don't get the width from **carousel-container.render-1**

```
.carouselContainer > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carouselContainer.render-1 > * {
  width: calc(100% - 10rem);
}
```

JSX:

```
import styles from './mycss.module.css'

<div className={classNames(`${styles.carouselContainer}`, 'render1')}>
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the React CSS module logic for the `render-1` class selector as well:

```
<div className={`${styles.carouselContainer} ${styles.render-1}`}>
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```